# Mink: Where are these methods defined?

Tags: php, mink

I'm learning Mink, and want to find an API reference. I've dug into the Mink source code for answers, but am baffled.

The documentation gives examples of its use:

```
$session->getPage()->hasContent("bla");
$session->getPage()->find('css', 'title')->getText();
```

But nowhere in the source can I find these methods `getPage`, `getText`, `find`, `hasContent`. (Yet they seem to work).

Mink seems to make the most out of OOP patterns, and I'm obviously not bright enough to work out what on earth is going on! **Can anyone give me a link to API reference, or help understanding where these methods are defined?**

For example, I've been puzzling why this doesn't work:

```
$this->assertTrue($session->getPage()->find('css', 'title')->hasContent("Part of the page's Title"));
```

(I get the error `Call to undefined method Behat\Mink\Element\NodeElement::hasContent()`)

But I can't find a glass called `NodeElement`, let alone what methods it has that I can use.

Comment: https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/search?p=3&q=getPage&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, never used Mink but the source is on github:

From https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/blob/master/src/Session.php:

```
/**
 * Returns page element.
 *
 * @return DocumentElement
 */
public function getPage()
{
    return $this->page;
}
```

Since getPage() returns a DocumentElement object, you can look at the DocumentElement class: https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/blob/master/src/Element/DocumentElement.php

Since DocumentElement extends TraversibleElement which extends Element, you'll eventually find the function find() in Element.  This is where an IDE really helps you traverse the code base to find where the function called is actually located.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am referring to the same Mink. Check out the source code over at github.

For the `getPage()`, for instance, see this 
https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/blob/master/src/Session.php

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should extend your `FeatureContext` class from `MinkContext`. MinkContext has lots of useful assert methods and methods which work with page elements. F.e.

`$this-> assertElementContains('CSS_IDENTIFIER_EXAMPLE', 'Some text');`

`$this->fillField($field, $value);`

Fills in form field with specified id|name|label|value.

The whole list of available methods check on [GitHub MinkContext](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php)

Also here is a [behat cheat sheet](http://blog.lepine.pro/images/2012-03-behat-cheat-sheet-en.pdf) which shows basic info and methods which work with html elements.